# Error when transfering EOS token on jungle testnet2 between my accounts

Tags: tokens, testnet, transfer

I've create 2 accounts on the testnet (jungle2) and funded one account with the faucet. I then tried to transfer some EOS to the other account. this is the command I've used but it's not working

```
cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action token transfer '["killbillvol2","lionkingvol1","6.0000 EOS","memo text"]' -p killbillvol2@active
```

this is the error message

```
error 2018-11-24T18:38:12.506 thread-0  main.cpp:3151                 main                 ] Failed with error: unspecified (0)
unknown key (eosio::chain::name): token
```

I'm using the same key for active and owner privileges for the user killbillvol2. I've created it in the jungle testnet 2 and in my local cleos wallet. Any suggestion  is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I tried mine with an EOS token contract didn't work. Got error unable to find key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the current up to date eos.io documentation v 1.3.2:

> https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/token-tutorial

instead of referring to token I reffered to **eosio.token**.

```
cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action eosio.token transfer '[ "killbillvol2", "lionkingvol1", "3.0000 EOS", "memo zr" ]' -p killbillvol2@active
```

Comment: Hi @luther, if this is the correct solution, consider marking it as the answer for others who might find this same question. Just click the large V next to the answer.Thanks!